# How was this answer posted ten minutes after its question was closed?

Tags: bug, closed-questions

The question [Why is bash history substitution still enabled by default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436505/why-is-bash-history-substitution-still-enabled-by-default) was closed at 2018-04-09-21:59:11Z. Ten minutes later, at 22:09:25Z [a (perfectly reasonable) answer was posted by Jason Goemaat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/436634/73093).

How was this possible? The [question's timeline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/436505/timeline) also shows the events in this order:

[image: Screenshot of timeline showing the above situation]

I first saw the answer when it appeared in the active questions list as "posted 7 seconds ago" to an "[on hold]" question. I thought it had been lucky to have barely made it in under the wire, but in fact the question had long been closed by then. I haven't seen this before and it seems either to be either a bug, or that I don't understand how question closure works.

Comment: some flaw in replication mecanism of SE (I forgot the name) ?

Comment: It’s probably [caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69172/307535)? I don’t know, but I wonder if they started typing their answer before the closure, creating a saved draft that counted as being before the cutoff in order to allow posting?

Comment: Possible MSE reference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79434/307535

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40962/307535

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the meta posts linked by Jeff suggest, there's a window after the question has been closed where an answer that was already being composed can be submitted. 10 minutes isn't particularly egregious, I have seen 30 minutes, and [a quick look at Data SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/edit/838071) shows much greater gaps (apologies for the crappy SQL, I haven't touched SQL in ages):

- [177 minutes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/232898/70524)
- [157 minutes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294715/70524)
- [151 minutes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389997)

This can happen when, for example, user composes an answer and:

- has a crappy network so the question closure is not reflected in their browser, and posts it (very likely on the phone app)
- puts their system to sleep and posts it soon after waking it